# Correct encoding for `<` in `alt` attributes in htlatex

Tags: pstricks, htlatex

When compiling the following document with `htlatex test.tex "xhtml,mathml"` the generated HTML document contains an unencoded `<` in the `alt` attribute of the image which is not XML standard-compliant.

What can I add to the configuration file to make htlatex correctly encode `<` as `&lt;` in the `alt` attributes?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\begin{document}
$\begin{pspicture}(0.8,1)
\psgrid(1,1)\end{pspicture}$
\end{document}
```

The body of the generated html document is (with a bit of formatting):

```
<p class="noindent" >
 <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="inline" >
  <img src="test0x.png" alt="<mi>P</mi><mi>I</mi><mi>C</mi>" class="pspicture" />
 </math>
</p>
```

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it is generating mathml, but the `pspicture` inside math is generating image. The `PIC` alt text is then converted to mathml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default alt text, `PIC`, is produced when `pspicture` is converted to image. Because you use it inside math, this alt text is treated as math text and each character is surrounded by `<mi>` element. We have two options - to put the alt text inside `\HCode` command, which will block the processing the text to mathml, or to remove it completely.

There is a special configuration for `pspicture` alt text, `pspictureAlt`. You can try the following configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml}

\Configure{pspictureAlt}{\HCode{pspicture figure}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

I noticed also another issue when I compiled your code: the `pstricks` to png failed with errors. I tried `dvipng` and `dvips` -> `ghostscript`. Only `dvisvgm` seems to work. If you use updated `TL 2016` distribution, you can request `dvisvgm` compilation if you add the following line the the configuration file:

```
\Configure{Picture}{.svg}
```

You can compile your document using:

```
make4ht -um draft -c configfilename.cfg test.tex
```

And this is the result:

```
<!--l. 4--><p class="noindent" ><!--l. 4--><math 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"  
display="inline" ><!--width="22.76227pt" height="28.45274pt"--><img 
src="sample0x.svg" alt="pspicture figure" class="pspicture" /></math>
</p>
```

[image]